# How to add blend mode to image?

Tags: html, css, hover, blend

I want to add a multiply blend mode effect on image when hover. Right now when I hover, it's just a solid colored layer with an opacity on top. I tried background-blend-mode but didn't work. Here's my code:

```css
.imgwrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.showtext:hover + div {
  display: block;
}
 
.showtext:hover {
 -webkit-filter:blur(2px);
 filter: blur(2px);
} 
 
.imagess:hover > .overlay {
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#b41f24;
    opacity:0.85;
    border-radius:0px;
}
.overlay #view {
 position: absolute;
  left: 108px;
  top: 108px;
color: white; 
 text-decoration:underline;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 250px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}
```

```html
<a href="single-illustration-sidebar-left.html" class="permalink">
     <div class="desktop-3 mobile-half columns">
      <div class="item">
       <h3>Pawsome</h3>
       <span class="category">ux/ui, web</span>

       
       <div class="imgwrapper">
     <div class="imagess">
       <img   class="showtext" src="images/thumb_item09.png" />
        <div class="overlay">
       <div id="view">view</div></div></div></div>
       
       </div>
      </div><!-- // .item -->
     <!-- // .desktop-3 -->
    </a>
```

Thank you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/apougher/6K6GS/ this might help

Answer (score 0):

This should help you.

You need to have the image as a `background-image` to add `blending-mode`.

```css
.imgwrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.showtext {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random);
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #b41f24;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.showtext:hover + div {
  display: block;
}
.showtext:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.overlay #view {
  position: absolute;
  left: 108px;
  top: 108px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 250px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<a href="single-illustration-sidebar-left.html" class="permalink">
  <div class="desktop-3 mobile-half columns">
    <div class="item">
      <h3>Pawsome</h3>
      <span class="category">ux/ui, web</span>


      <div class="imgwrapper">
        <div class="imagess">
          <div class="showtext"></div>
          <div class="overlay">
            <div id="view">view</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- // .item -->
  <!-- // .desktop-3 -->
</a>
```

Comment: thank you, it works. But is there a way to just blur the image and not the multiply layer?

Comment: I've removed the styles for the `overlay` layer. The blend mode and the image will come together.

Comment: it still blurs the multiply layer for me, I  just want to blur the image, not the red layer.

Comment: What do you mean by multiply layer? I dont see any multiply layer!

Comment: I mean the red layer that overlays the image when hover, is there a way to not blur it?

Comment: It won't get blurred! The blending is independent  of the overlay layer!